# Iterate through 2 loops in GAE Python templates

Tags: python, list, google-app-engine, jinja2

I am using Jinja2 template in python for Google App Engine. I need to iterate through 2 lists list1 and list2 in the same loop in the html file. I tried using zip as described in some of the posts but it is not working. 
Something similar in C : `for(i=0.j=0; I<len(list1) && j < len(list2) ; I++,j++)`

Can anyone suggest some ways to implement the same?

Comment: What do the lists look like and how are they related. Also, can you show what your jinja template looks like?

Answer (score 0):

If you have `list1` and `list2`, you can use `list` and define it like this:

```
list = zip(list1[:min(len(list1), len(list2))], list2[:min(len(list1), len(list2))])
```

or better yet

```
size = min(len(list1), len(list2))
list = zip(list1[:size], list2[:size])
```

Example:

```
>>> list1 = [1,2,3,4]
>>> list2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
>>> list = zip(list1[:min(len(list1), len(list2))], list2[:min(len(list1), len(list2))])
>>> list
[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4)]
```

Note that `zip` only works with lists of equal length.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use `itertools.product(list1, list2)`. This will create all combinations of list1 and list2.

For example, if list1 =  [1,2] and list2 = [1,2,3] then itertools.products(list1,list2) = [ (1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3)]